# Grails- WSClient for SSL

Tags: ssl, grails, wsdl, ws-client

I am using WSClient to connect to a wsdl server.

```
def proxy = new MyWSClient("https://", this.class.classLoader)
proxy.initialize()
```

All works as expected with http request.
But when I use SSL(https) I get an error "The document has moved", in the browser it appears.

I do see that the plugin connected to the server since i get the prints of the plugin of the available methods:

```
 INFO MyWSClient - available method: {http://...}checkCredentials
```

Questions:

1. in the print of available methods, as can be seen, the service is http and not https - why?
2. Does WSClient support SSL calls?
3. Is there a better way to implement a call to a wsdl in grails?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know about [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) which definitely supports ssl and has an example of how to use https in the documentation...

Comment: I didn't know that it supports ssl, i will take a look at it. Thanks!